# FIWARE Orion Context Broker fails to return token

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

It seems that since last Orion Context Broker update the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client/master/token_script.sh stopped working.

The script and curl to https://orion.lab.fiware.org/token hangs and doesn't return token.
Any chance that token API or url been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have experience some connectivity problems to the local infrastructure supporting the `orion.lab.fiware.org` host. The problems use to happen from time to time but they doesn't use to take very long.

The problem is now solved and token provide service is back to work. Thus, the `token_script.sh` should be working again.